# Compact image encoding in Java

Tags: java, encoding

I would like to encode/decode an image in an encoding like `base64`.  However, I'm not using `base64` because the encoded result is too large: I want the encoded size to be small.

I've searched Google many times, but have not found any useful information for my requirement.

Can anyone help me to find a more compact encoding than `base64`?

Comment: Base64 is not an encryption, it is an encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to compress an image to as small as possible and transfer it? Or are you trying to encrypt it's data to prevent others from reading it?

Comment: i want to encoding image and save it to database and other some purpose encoded string too small any encoding alternative for base64?

Comment: Why encode at all? Simply use a binary field(blob). If you really want to turn it into a string, you need to specify which characters are valid, from that the best encoding follows trivially. And how is this specific to images? How are images different from other binary data?

Comment: Then your question has simply nothing to do with encryption.

Comment: So let's start with the basics, you just want to save a binary object to a database. Is the requirement to save it in an existing varchar field? If so the resulting payload is most likely to always be larger than the original because well it's text. I would do as CodesInChaos says and just save it as a binary field in a table

Comment: but,my project requirement save only it's only string to database!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement is that the encoded image must be printable in ASCII, then Base64 is probably a good generic bet. If your requirement is really to have as small a binary representation of your image as possible, look into [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Encoding) and [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) (depending on the type of image, requirement of lossy/lossless etc). If you have a lot of time on your hands and want to fiddle with mathematics, try [fractal compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_compression)?

As others have commented, if your requirement is to store an image in a database, most/all RDBMS provide some form of [BLOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) to achieve just that.

Cheers,